# Number of permutation operations to return to original array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I recently solved this in a coding assessment for an application (in C++, Python wasn't allowed).

I've re-done the problem (with the same logic) in Python with a problem statement.

My brute force solution got 6/15 of the test cases (the rest were time limit exceeded).

My optimal got 8/15, with the rest being incorrect. The ones where it was incorrect were hidden test cases, with very large output. I verified the issue was not due to the calculation of the LCM and not due to integer overflow, leaving the logic of the program (the cycle detection).

Problem statement:

```
# return the number of permutation operations required to get an array back to the original (at minimum 1 must be done)
# permutation operation defined as
# tmp[i] = arr[p[i]] for all i
# arr = tmp
# where p is an array of non-zero length n with distinct values 0 - (n - 1) as elements
# array is arbitrary array of length n
```

Brute force:

```
# O(n^2) since max cycle is at worst n long
def brute_force_sol(p):
    n = len(p)
    arr = [i for i in range(n)]
    num = 0
    while True:
        tmp = [0] * n
        for i in range(n):
            tmp[i] = arr[p[i]]
        arr = tmp
        num += 1
        if arr == [i for i in range(n)]:
            break
    return num
```

Optimal:

```
# idea:
# observe that since 0 - (n - 1) are present, with each being a directed edge
# there form cycles that may sync up occassionally. we want to know when
# all the cycles sync up since that is the number of ops to get back to orig
# OR we want the LCM of the length of all the cycles present in the graph

# example:
# p = [1, 4, 3, 2, 0]
# cycle one: 0 -> 1 -> 4 -> 0 (len 3)
# cycle two: 2 -> 3 -> 2 (len 2)
# LCM(2, 3) = 6

# p = [0, 1]
# cycle one: 0 -> 0
# cycle two: 1 -> 1
# LCM(1, 1) = 1

# O(n)
def optimal_sol(p):
    n = len(p)
    a = set()
    cycles = []
    for i in range(n):
        if i in a:
            continue
        else:
            # track the cycle len
            j = i
            start = j
            cycleLen = 0
            
            while True:
                a.add(j)
                j = p[j]
                cycleLen += 1
                if start == j:
                    break
            cycles.append(cycleLen)

    from math import lcm
    return lcm(*cycles)
```

I'm hoping for someone to be able to give me an idea of where my algorithm is incorrect. I've written it up in Python for viewing convenience.

Comment: Sorry.  I deleted my answer and will comment on yours.  I misread one feature of it that was important.  Yes, it appears to be correct.  You get linear behavior by only looking at each cycle on its smallest element and never looking at it again.

Comment: Exactly. That is my confusion @FrankYellin. It appears to be correct, but I was missing test cases for my incorrect output. I am wondering what I am missing in my logic.

Comment: I even added `assert sum(cycles) == len(p)` and your code is fine.  Is there something special you're supposed to do if the lcm is large?  It can grow very quickly.

Comment: "*The ones where it was incorrect were hidden test cases, with very large output.*" Do you have any idea what the outputs were exactly?

Comment: Can you share or link to the inputs that failed?

Comment: I cannot say much about the test cases except the outputs were large. This was from an assessment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we need it to be reproducible. There is even a closure reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your algorithm looks generally correct. I implemented a similar solution in Java with a slight difference in logic, and it passed all the test cases.

One thing I noticed is that you don't seem to be using the provided modulo (10^7) in your code, which might explain the issues with overflowed integers. Remember to not only mod the result, but also when computing lcm.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done by using DSU.

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
#define int long long
#define MAX 10000003
using namespace std;
vector<int> par, Size;
int prime[MAX];
const int mod = 1000000007;
map<int, int> maxMap;
class DisjointSet {
  public:
    DisjointSet(int n) {
      par.resize(n);
      iota(par.begin(), par.end(), 0);
      Size.resize(n);
      Size.assign(n, 1);
    }
    int findSet(int X)  {
      if (par[X] == X)
        return X;
      return par[X] = findSet(par[X]);
    }
    void unionSet(int X, int Y) {
      X = findSet(X);
      Y = findSet(Y);
      if (X != Y) {
        if (Size[X] < Size[Y])  {
          swap(X, Y);
        }
        Size[X] += Size[Y];
        par[Y] = X;
      }
    }
};
signed main()   {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  vector<int> p(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> p[i];
  }
  DisjointSet dsu(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    dsu.unionSet(i, p[i]);
  }
  set<int> Par;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Par.insert(dsu.findSet(i));
  }
  auto binPow = [&] (int base, int pow) {
    int rs = 1;
    while (pow) {
      if (pow & 1)  (rs *= base) %= mod;
      (base *= base) %= mod;
      pow >>= 1;
    }
    return rs;
  };
  auto lcm = [&] (vector<int> a) {
    memset(prime, 0, sizeof(prime));
    prime[0] = prime[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < MAX; ++i) {
      if (!prime[i])  {
        for (int j = i; j < MAX; j += i)  {
          if (!prime[j])  {
            prime[j] = i;
          }
        }
        prime[i] = i;
      }
    }
    int sz = a.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)  {
      int num = a[i];
      map<int, int> tmp;
      while (num > 1) {
        int fact = prime[num];
        ++tmp[fact];
        num /= fact;
      }
      for (auto it : tmp) {
        maxMap[it.first] = max(it.second, maxMap[it.first]);
      }
    }
    int rs = 1;
    for (auto it : maxMap)  {
      rs = rs * binPow(it.first, it.second) % mod;
    }
    return rs;
  };
  int op = 1;
  vector<int> a;
  for (int w : Par) {
    a.push_back(Size[w]);
  }
  int ans = lcm(a);
  cout << ans;
}
```